# Equivalent measure to Matthews correlation coefficient, MCC, for multiclass classification

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, classification, model-selection, model-comparison

Thanks in advance for the help.

MCC gives a measure of the quality of a binary classifier.  I'm looking for a similar measure that can be used for a multi-class classifier.  Ultimately what I would like to do is to compare several multi-class classifiers that I have created.  I could simply look at percent correct, but I would like a secondary measure since percent correct can sometimes be misleading (especially in cases of class imbalance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0041882

They have the definition of MCC for the multiclass case. It is easy to implement it by yourself based on eq.2